# Finding valid function parameters in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, math

I have a lot of mathematical functions written in C++ and VBA which I load into Excel and want to test. Many of these functions have many parameters (varies between 3 - 6).

Although I know the ranges/limits for all these parameters I know that for some allowed parameter combinations the function won't compute, but return a error or a non valid value.

I want to test these functions with different parameters, to see which parameters returns valid values.

I thought about using RANDBETWEEN function in to generate a bunch of parameters within allowed ranges, and make e.g. 1000 rows, and see which parameters give a valid answer.

But is there a more systematic approach I could use?

If it would be only 3 parameters I would plot 3D surfaces of every function.

Comment: This question is too vague to answer. How you would test a function depends heavily on what that function *is*. For example, it would depend in part on what sort of inputs represent edge cases, etc.

Comment: If you want to test *systematically* then you'd need to loop over a set of arguments covering the expected ranges of each of the parameters - no need for randomness...  Are the parameter values continuous, or discrete, or both?

Comment: @TimWilliams The inputs are continuous double values. Some have ranges between 0 to 20M, others have ranges between 0.0 and 1.0. So it varies alot. I thought I would step incrementally 10% from min allowed range to max allowed range. Even so it would be a crazy amount of listing all possible combinations.

Comment: @JohnColeman See answer to Tim

Comment: It isn't clear what you are testing *for*. If the inputs are doubles, then there are *billions* of possible inputs for each variable (and you say that some functions take up to 6 variables). Without some assumptions on the nature of a function, there is no guarantee that stepping through inputs on a grid won't step over some problem inputs. It would greatly help if you provide an *example* which illustrates just what the problem is. Also, what do you mean by "for some allowed parameter combinations the function won't compute" -- if a parameter "won't compute" in what sense is it "allowed"?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for trying to understand. It's true that it's impossible to cover all problematic combinations by stepping. And mathematically all combinations will compute, but the functions programmatically return errors because the result is out of allowed bounds.

Comment: Without more details, your question is impossible to answer in a meaningful way. If by "out of allowed bounds" you mean exceeds or fails to meet some threshold, you might need mathematical methods (e.g. the solution of a system of inequalities) rather than computer testing.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me out which direction to go.